# Running nunit gui from asp.net mvc web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit

I am trying to launch the nunit gui app from an asp.net mvc web page (don't judge!) Here is the controller code:

```
[AuthorizeUser]
    public class TestController : ApplicationController
    {
        //GET: /Test/Index/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //start process.
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"H:\Navtrak\Test\NUnit\nunit.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"H:\Navtrak\Test\TestCases\SystemTest\bin\Debug\SystemTest.dll";
            process.Start();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

It actually launches nunit.exe (I can see it in task manager), however it does so silently. The nunit gui app doesn't actually show up. Is there some setting on Process that I'm missing or is this related to launching it from an MTAThread in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running through IIS? If so, it runs as a service. Have you checked the "Allow sdervice to interact with the desktop" on the "Log On" tab?

Comment: I think you're on to something, however I can't find that setting (or the login tab) anywhere in IIS 6 or 7.5. Any idea where it'd be?

Comment: On Win7 it is on the the service itself: Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Services > World Wide Web Publishing Service > Properties > Log On Tab.

Comment: I made that change and restarted the service, however it still doesn't launch the nunit gui.